# Updating keyboard focus when implementing the skip to main content technique through an anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, accessibility

I'm implementing the *skip to main content* technique described in [W3C's WCAG2.0 Techniques documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/general.html#G1), however I'm struggling to update the keyboard focus when activating the link. (Note that I'm testing this on the latest public version of Chrome).

Firstly, here is my JavaScript function:

```js
function skipToMainContent() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (hash === "main") {
        var el = document.getElementById(hash);
        el.tabIndex = 0;
        el.focus();
    }
}
skipToMainContent();
```

What this function does is firstly pull the `hash` from the URL and remove the `#`; then it checks if the value of the hash variable is equal to "main"; if so it then gets our `id="main"` element, sets its `tabIndex` to 0 to make it focusable and then gives it focus.

If I visit `http://example.com/#main`, the `skipToMainContent()` function is fired and my keyboard focus is set accordingly. When I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> the first interactive element within my `main` content area is focussed. (Note that without this function, Chrome will focus the first interactive element on the page instead, so this function definitely works here).

However when I attempt to trigger this function through a link on my page, the above does not apply:

```html
<a href="#main" onclick="skipToMainContent()">
    Skip to Main Content
</a>
<nav>...</nav>
<main role="main" id="main">...</main>
```

Upon clicking my *Skip to Main Content* link, the `skipToMainContent()` function is fired appropriately and my `main` element is given a `tabIndex` of `0`, however it doesn't appear to get focussed. If I hit the <kbd>tab</kbd> key after clicking my link the first interactive element within my `nav` is focussed instead.

What do I need to do to ensure that when my "skip" link is clicked, my `main` element is focussed?

Note that I've tried adding both `this.blur()` and `document.activeElement.blur()` before calling `el.focus()`, but with this the next focussed element was my "skip" link again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, 'window.location.hash' is empty on click.

I would also suggest that you apply `tabindex="-1"` rather than 0, which means the main is in the tab-order. Using -1 means you can programmatically focus on the element, but it is not in the default order.

Also, for posterity (and people finding this later) my generally solution would be to use something like this:

HTML Skip link:

```
<a href="#main" id="skiplink">Skip to content</a>
```

HTML Target:

```
<main role="main" id="main" tabindex=”-1”>
```

JS:

```
$("#skiplink").click(function() {
    $('main').focus();
});
```

CSS:

```
main:focus {outline: 0;}
```

You can of course apply more of that through JavaScript, that's up to you.

It might help to put the tabindex attribute in the HTML.

Comment: Regardless of the `tabIndex` setting, the focus isn't applied to the `main` element when the anchor link is clicked. It *is* applied when the user navigates manually to `http://example.com/#main`.

Comment: Your JS applies onload, so if the user presses the link no tabindex is applied. Perhaps add the JS from my answer with a line to add tabindex?

Comment: Or, perhaps the reliance on the hash detection is the issue, as it might not apply in time to work. Try adding the tabindex in the HTML.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I realise what I've done wrong now. `window.location.hash` is empty when clicking on the link.