# Tab Index Relative to User View

Tags: jquery, html, seo, accessibility, tabindex

I'm optimizing my website to be accessible to everybody first starting with tabbing. I has a hidden link that appears on `:focus` which is the very first link. The purpose of the link is to "Jump To Main Content" which I thought was a cool feature to add in. The problem with this is even though it jumps the user to the main content, if they tab their screen jumps right back to the top of the page...

**Is there such a thing as tabbing relative to where the top of the users screen is?**

I was thinking of using JQuery and adding the `tabindex` attribute to the closest link once they jump to the main content but I wasn't sure how SEO would handle that. Since it is being added dynamically theoretically it should be ignored by search engines and would never see my `tabindex` starting in the middle of my page. *From a SEO or Accessibility standpoint, is there anything wrong with this approach?* Is there a better approach?

For people to get a better idea of what I mean I've [created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpvycrxs/3/) - you have to click the Display box then tab through it to get the "Jump To Main Content" link to show. Though when I add a tabindex dynamically it gets ignored.

Comment: I don't think you need to adjust tabindex at all.  Rather, focus on the first form field in view instead of the hidden link.  the 'next' tab will go in order from there.

Comment: @briansol I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm talking about a full page website, not necessarily a form. Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: Does it happen in Firefox and IE or only Chrome? Chrome is buggy and I can't remember if it's been fixed in Canary or Canary-1 but I think it is

Comment: As a general rule: do not muck with the natural tab order. You're more likely to confuse and annoy users that navigate with the keyboard than not.

Comment: @steveax the tab order would be entirely optional since I wouldn't only append `tabindex` when the user decides to jump to the main content. The purpose is so when the user tabs again it doesn't jump back to the top of the page. I've added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpvycrxs/3/) to my question to better convey what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a bug in Blink/Webkit where the keyboard focus doesn't move when you follow in page links, I answered that here: [Uptating keyboard focus when implementing the skip to main content technique through an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858001/uptating-keyboard-focus-when-implementing-the-skip-to-main-content-technique-thr/19859641#19859641)

I would completely avoid trying to do dynamic tabindex, it is not needed and will almost certainly break when you update things in future.