# Firefox does not set focus to anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, accessibility

I have created a [Skip to Content](https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/#maincontent) link on my page that skips to a button. In IE and Chrome, the focus is set on the button which allows me to activate it with Enter. In Firefox however, it does not set focus to the button. It seems to be focusing *after* the button as I need to Shift+Tab (Tab backwards) to get focus on the button.

```
<a href="#player__button">Skip to play button</a>

<button id="player__button">
  Play
</button>
```

I've created a Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chadfawcett/p4t2wv21/5/. You should be able to reproduce the issue by Tabbing to the **Skip to play button** link, hitting **Enter**, which will put focus on the button. In Chrome and IE you can then hit **Enter** repeatedly to have the onclick listener fire.

Comment: If you surround it with a label, it would probably click it.... `<label for="player__button"><a href="#player__button">Skip to play button</a></label>` Doubt it it is what you are after

Comment: It works for me on Firefox 59.0b6 Developer Edition, what version are you using?

Comment: @epascarello Unfortunately that does not fix the issue.

Comment: @VitorM.Barbosa I've tested it with 58.0.1 on Mac and Windows

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug in Firefox since many and many years (2005 at least) :

[Following an on-page anchor link loses the focus](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308064)

The visual focus is changed, but not the keyboard focus

> *The only thing Gecko does correct and Blink, WebKit and Trident fail is updating the "sequential focus navigation starting point" when :target is not focusable.*

There's also an open similar bug which concerns form elements:

[form controls should get focus when a URI points to them (with a fragment identifier)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=277178)

Comment: Thanks for the linked references @Adam

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question up, I was able to find a JS workaround, but I would prefer an HTML solution. **Hopefully someone can chime in with a better answer.**

After finding this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858001/updating-keyboard-focus-when-implementing-the-skip-to-main-content-technique-thr), I was able to get the desired behaviour working in Firefox by using Javascript to set the focus.

```
link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  button.focus()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chadfawcett/p4t2wv21/8/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this fixes your issue. It just comes down to code interpretation between browsers, and changing the syntax of your code to less ambiguous/more universal is key.

https://jsfiddle.net/ws88pwo6/3/

```
<button type="button" onclick="focusMethod()">Skip to play button</button>
<p></p>

<button id="player__button">
Play
</button>
<textarea id="output" disabled>

</textarea>
```

Js

```
const button = document.getElementById('player__button')
const output = document.getElementById('output')

focusMethod = function getFocus() {          
document.getElementById("player__button").focus();
}

player__button.onclick = function(){output.innerHTML += 'Button clicked\n'};
```

Comment: I was hoping to use a non JS approach just with the anchor tag

Comment: There is no non-JS approach with setting focus to elements. JS is required.

Comment: my initial code does not use JS to add focus to the button. The browser does it by either tabbing, or clicking the link that sets focus to the button by linking to its ID.

Comment: I didn't mean you can't `a href` to a div in HTML. Of course you can.

And also, you are correct, you can tab around a webpage with links, and you can jump to an anchor in some browsers with html.

But as you yourself stated it's not working in Firefox, and I'm telling you that you need Javascript or Jquery to program it in an unambiguous manner.